# how to conscription of numbers in r. adding double quotes to numbers

Tags: r

I'm loading numbers from a file,

```
chory
[1] 9 4 2 8
```

to display a graph needs to have the form `"9" "4" "2" "8"` for example

Comment: I found the answer,
topic to be snapped up
Regards !
cat(gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', chory))

Comment: Does `dQuote` work? Seems simpler.

Comment: @r2evans I wonder if `as.character` would cut it.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I was inferring that the quotation marks were part of the string.